# How to use multiple ISAPI redirect dlls in IIS 6 (for each site its own isapi dll)

Tags: iis, tomcat, iis-6

I have a configured IIS 6 where already a page is defined which is using a ISAPI dll for redirecting the incoming requests to the underlying tomcats. Now I want to add a new page and use for this page its own isapi dll, but this wont work on my side. The state of the isapi redirect wont change to active

Here you can see the missing state of the redirect
http://pbrd.co/TwXwCQ

Isnt that possible to have multiple sites on a iis where each one is using its own redirect dll? Or how can i achieve it that the requests to my site will be redirected to my underlying tomcats.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing here is an ISAPI filter.  These can be installed at the Service level making them global (affecting all sites) or they can be applied at the site level makign them local (only affect the single site).

If the filter in question is supported for use at the site level then there should be no problem configuring an instnaeof the filter for each site.  If the filter is only supported at a global level then you would need to look into the configuration to see if there is some means of configuring the filter to take specfic action based on which site (or perhaps page) the request is initially directed to.

In this particular case I would suggest reviewing the Tomcat documentation to see how to configure their ISAPI filter properly.